# How do I reference a class without calling it?

Tags: java, class, methods, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm making a hangman game, but really all that is causing a problem is my method `PanDisp` and my class `LabelChangeListener`. I want to add a `KeyListener` and and `ActionListener` to the repective classes (`KeyInput` and `LabelChangeListener`), but when I do I need to reference the classes they are in, when I run the program I get a `StackOverflowError` because when I call the class, I get stuck in an infinite loop constantly calling `LabelChangeListener` and then calling `PanDisp()`.

My question is how can I reference these classes and add their respective listeners without calling them in a loop?

```
public class PanDisp extends JPanel {

    JLabel lblOutput;
    JLabel lblGuess;
    JButton btnUpdateLabel;
    Image imgPkmn;
    FraImg fraImg;
    String sSecret;

    public PanDisp() {//Constructor
        KeyInput keyInput = new KeyInput();
        KeyInput.LabelChangeListener labelChange = keyInput.new LabelChangeListener();
        sSecret = "*******";
        lblGuess = new JLabel("Type will go here");
        lblOutput = new JLabel(sSecret);
        btnUpdateLabel = new JButton("Enter");
        add(lblOutput);
        add(btnUpdateLabel);
        addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
        setFocusable(true);
        btnUpdateLabel.addActionListener(labelChange);
        fraImg = new FraImg(imgPkmn);
        //fraImg.main();
    }

    public void GameOver() {

    }

    class KeyInput implements KeyListener {

        String sInput;
        String sWord = "pikachu";
        String sSecret = "*******";
        char chInput;

        /*keyPressed - when the key goes down
        keyReleased - when the key comes up
        keyTyped - when the unicode character represented by this key is sent by the keyboard to system input.*/
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            chInput = (char) e.getKeyChar();
            sInput = String.valueOf(chInput); // convert the char to a String
            lblOutput.setText(sInput);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        class LabelChangeListener implements ActionListener {

            char cWord;
            int nCorrect, nIncorrect, nNum;
            PanDisp panDisp = new PanDisp();

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                if (sWord.contains(sInput)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sWord.length(); i++) {
                        sSecret.replace(sSecret.charAt(i), sWord.charAt(i));

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a new PanDisp in your LabelChangeListener? You don't even use it.

Comment: Hmm. I guess i just got on a roll and added it by force of habit. Stupid mistake nonetheless. Thanks for pointing that out! :D

Comment: so this solves the problem then?